# Clicked link more visible than unclicked one

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, design

This is a snapshot of my review page, and the top one is a clicked link while the bottom one is unclicked.

[image]

You can see how the unclicked one is brighter (probably in line with the color scheme), while the clicked one is a more intense blue. IMO this can be confusing, as a clicked link should be a bit faded, to give more importance to unseen content.

What do you think?

Comment: What "review page"?  I don't think I've ever seen a page like that.

Comment: @OlinLathrop at the right of your nickname, after the badges

Comment: @OlinLathrop, you probably dont have the rep yet. [You can test with a direct link](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/).

Comment: @Kortuk: Ha. ____________________ dummy text